# Start at particular field value when sorting with Solr

Tags: solr, solr4

With Solr I can sort results by field and start at a particular result number; however, I would like to start at a particular field value instead (or in addition to). For example, I have a library of books that I want to sort by title and start at the H's. In SQL it would look something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Books
WHERE title >= 'H'
ORDER BY title
LIMIT 10
```

Can this be done in Solr? I want to be able to do this in Solr and not a separate database because I already use Solr for my search engine and I want to take advantage of features like facets.

I'm using Solr 4.7.0, but I am able to upgrade to newer versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try filter query with range title:[H* to Z*]?

Let me know if you need more info or exact query.

Comment: Thanks Ravi. Using a filter query worked great. I modified the query slightly so I didn't have to specify an upperbound : `title:[H* to *]`. I also found the function query frange useful when I didn't want to do a `<=`, but rather a `<` : `{!frange l='H' incl=false}title`.